# Flink dont close window with EventTimeWindows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Why does this code not give out anything?
If i change to `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` - all work fine.

I did not find in the documentation what else I MUST add? Triggers? Evictors?
Allowed Lateness?

```
  WatermarkStrategy<UserModel> strategy = WatermarkStrategy.<UserModel>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .withTimestampAssigner((i, timestamp) -> Timestamp.valueOf(i.dt).getTime());

        ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(strategy)
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10))).reduce((acc, i) -> {
                    acc.count += i.count;
                    acc.dt = i.dt;
                    return acc;
                }).addSink(new PrintSinkFunction());
```

Input:

```
{"userId":1,"count":11,"dt":"2023-04-11T09:29:12.244"}
```

System time = Input time

**Update 2:**

1. I added some print information to `withTimestampAssigner` - its called on every event.
2. I added OutputTag for catch dropped events - its clear.

   OutputTag lateTag = new OutputTag("late"){};
3. I added debug print internal to reduce function - its called on every event.

But print (sink) for close output window there is not =(

All code:

```
 private static void m4(DataStream<UserModel> ds) {
        WatermarkStrategy<UserModel> strategy = WatermarkStrategy.<UserModel>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .withTimestampAssigner((i, timestamp) -> {
                    long time = i.dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
                    System.out.println(i.dt + " is: " + time +  " dont know: " + timestamp);
                    return time;
                });

        OutputTag<UserModel> lateTag = new OutputTag<UserModel>("late"){};

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<UserModel> reduce = ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(strategy)
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .sideOutputLateData(lateTag)
                .reduce((acc, i) -> {
                    System.out.println(i.dt + " reDUCE:");
                    acc.count += i.count;
                    acc.dt = i.dt;
                    return acc;
                });
                reduce.getSideOutput(lateTag).print();

                reduce.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction());


    }
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Reply to @kkrugler.
It's interesting that `TumblingEventTimeWindows` needs `ProcessAllWindowFunction`, although `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` **works without it**.

So I added `ProcessAllWindowFunction`, but again **no result**, I added print to debug and this part of the code is **not called**.

Interesting point if i change to `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows`, window close and **sink** EVEN without `ProcessAllWindowFunction`
[image]

All code:

```
public class Rich extends ProcessAllWindowFunction<UserModel, UserModelEx, TimeWindow> {
    @Override
    public void process(ProcessAllWindowFunction<UserModel, UserModelEx, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<UserModel> iterable, Collector<UserModelEx> collector) throws Exception {
        UserModel um = iterable.iterator().next();
        System.out.println(um.count + " rich:" + um.dt);
        collector.collect(new UserModelEx() {{
            userId = um.userId;
            count = um.count;
            wStart = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(context.window().getStart()), ZoneOffset.UTC);
            wEnd = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(context.window().getEnd()), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        }});
    }
}

 private static void m4(DataStream<UserModel> ds) {

        WatermarkStrategy<UserModel> strategy = WatermarkStrategy.<UserModel>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .withTimestampAssigner((i, timestamp) -> {
                    long time = i.dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
                    System.out.println(i.dt + " assignEvent: " + time + " : " + timestamp);
                    return time;
                });


        SingleOutputStreamOperator<UserModelEx> reduce = ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(strategy)
                .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
                .reduce((acc, i) -> {
                    acc.count += i.count;
                    acc.dt = i.dt;
                    System.out.println(acc.dt + " reduce:" + acc.count);
                    return acc;
                }, new Rich());

        reduce.print();

        //reduce.addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<UserModelEx>());


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 4 days I found the problem, but I can't explain why it's necessary.

`env.setParallelism(1);` - solves my problem.

I am reading from Kafka from topic partition = 1, i.e. by default the parallelism should be 1.

I hope the experts will explain why my example needs this parameter...

Answer (score -1):

Normally you'd provide a ProcessAllWindowFunction with the reduce call, see [this API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/AllWindowedStream.html#reduce-org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessAllWindowFunction-). The [ProcessAllWindowFunction.process](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/windowing/ProcessAllWindowFunction.html#process-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessAllWindowFunction.Context-java.lang.Iterable-org.apache.flink.util.Collector-) method will be called for each window, with a single element (the result of all reduce calls) provided by the iterator.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I've been poking around with a basic example for three days now. Wrote the results in Update 3. @kkrugler